# Windows 10 reboot when try to copy files through VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, powershell

I'm try to copy some files from client Windows 10 to Windows Server 2021 R2 machine; I have access to this Windows Server 2012 R2 by Dell Sonic Wall VPN. My Windows 10 client contains more than two off board Network Cards and I grouping these using by New-NetSwitchTeam PowerShell cdmlet (similar of Nic Team grouping). The file copy is using Windows Explorer and during the copying, my Windows 10 machine reboot in every trying.

Any idea?

---

EDIT:
I have same behavior using another Machine (with Windows 10, off board Network Cards and these networks cards grouped by New-NetSwitchTeam, but different hardware).

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: Definitely a bug and if it's a reboot, it is probably hardware related, so as a first step I would make sure drivers for all network cards are up to date, then I would disable most cards other than the ones you absolutely need for the test and add them one-by-one to see is happening. Try changing drivers too, sometimes the bug is in the new one.

Comment: @Itai, I'm sorry, but I need to update the question: I have same behavior using another machine with same client VPN.